# How to sideload {json:api} records with Ember Data 2 and JSONAPI::Resources in Rails?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I'm developing an Ember app with a Rails backend, using the excellent [JSONAPI::Resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) gem to expose my data.

I'd like to fetch records from my the backend using `store.findRecord`, `store.query`, etc. while sideloading certain relationships. JSONAPI::Resources [supports](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources#included-relationships-side-loading-resources) [this part of the spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes) but I can't figure out how to make Ember Data include the `?include=...` parameter in the request URL.

How can I instruct Ember Data (2.2.0) to ask the backend to include relationships when fetching resources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are able, you can try out the Ember Data 2.4 beta, which includes the [`ds-finder-include`](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/12/ember-data-2-3-released.html#toc_code-ds-finder-include-code) feature flag.

This feature flag enables you to pass an options hash with an `includes` key.

To learn how to enable feature flags check the [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/configuring-ember/feature-flags/).

Comment: It looks like this is only enabled for `findRecord` and `findAll` -- bummer because I'm using `query` to filter on certain values. My sense is that it's not included in `query` because `query` is so low-level -- is that it? Are there any workaround you recommend?

Comment: A query is a query, you can pass anything you want, including `includes`!

Answer (score 4):

The way I handle this is by modifying my application adapter to process includes, and then pass includes as my adapter options in my query. Right now I only handle a single include, but it shouldn't be too hard to handle an array.

app/adapters/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({

  urlForFindRecord(query, modelName, snapshot) {
    var url = this._super(...arguments);

    return this._processIncludes(url, snapshot);
  },

  urlForFindAll(query, modelName, snapshot) {
    var url = this._super(...arguments);

    return this._processIncludes(url, snapshot);
  },

  _processIncludes(url, snapshot) {
    var options = snapshot && snapshot.adapterOptions;

    if (options && options.include) {
      url = `${url}?include=${options.include}`;
    }

    return url;
  },


});
```

And then, in my routes model hook, I just add my adapter options.

```
return this.store.findRecord('myModel', params.id, {
  adapterOptions: {
    include: ['myChildModel']
  }
```